# Using Markov Chain to transfom a RGB image to black and white(0-1)

Tags: python, image, machine-learning, image-processing, markov-chains

I am struggling to find an answer to this question,i have not understand well Markov chain use and i would like some help:

[Input image] https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9XCE.png

[Output image example] https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pllU.png

This is what we begin with, classic.

I want to transform this image in black and white only BUT i have to use Markov chain probabilities which I don't understand at all

Is anyone able to give me somme hint?
I believe that we have to pick random pixel N number of time and to apply somme proba magic to change it to black or white (based on probabilities and neighbors)

thanks in advance (i'm not searching for code particulary but the logic to be implemented)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to binarize the image with Markov chain:

Assuming (by Markov property) that a pixel value depends only on its neighbors (let's assume a 4-nbd), let's estimate the probability that a pixel is white given that n of its nbd pixels are white, i.e., for 4-nbd, let's first compute the conditional probabilities that P(x(i,j)=1 | n of its nbrs are also 1), where n=0,1,2,3,4 for 4-nbd (also, let's use a global thresholding to compute the probabilities as shown in the following code, this can be thought of as the training phase):

```
from skimage.io import imread
im = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9XCE.png')

def count_nbrs(im, i, j, th): # counts number of nbd pixels are 1 given a pixel, with threshold th
    count = 0
    count += np.mean(im[i-1,j]) > th
    count += np.mean(im[i+1,j]) > th
    count += np.mean(im[i,j-1]) > th
    count += np.mean(im[i,j+1]) > th
    return count

th = 140 #np.mean(im) # a global threshold
nnbrs = 5 # use 4-nbd
freq = np.zeros(nnbrs)
tot = np.zeros(nnbrs)
h, w, _ = im.shape
for i in range(1, h-1):
   for j in range(1, w-1):
      count = count_nbrs(im, i, j, th)
      if np.mean(im[i,j]) > th:
         freq[count] += 1
      tot[count] += 1
prob = freq/tot 
print(prob)
# Prob(x(i,j)=1|n of its nbrs are 1) in the image, for n=0,1,2,3,4
# [0.00775595 0.09712838 0.48986784 0.91385768 0.99566323]
```

Now let's use these estimated probabilities to change each of the pixels in the colored image to black and white, depending on its nbd (this can be thought of as testing phase):

```
h, w, _ = im.shape
im1 = np.zeros((h, w))
for i in range(1, h-1):
    for j in range(1, w-1):
        c = count_nbrs(im, i, j, th) # count number of neighbors with white pixel
        im1[i,j] = 255*(prob[c] > 0.5) # use Prob vector to determine value of the pixel
plt.imshow(im1, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

The binary image obtained has far better quality than global thresholding (check it out).

[image]

You could randomly choose pixels and compute the probability that a pixel value will be 1 given the number of 1 nbrs (thresholded), accordingly setting the pixel value, using the following code with large number of iterations N,  it will result in similar binary image.

```
N = 100000
h, w, _ = im.shape
im1 = np.zeros((h, w))
for k in range(N):
    i = np.random.randint(1,h-1,1)[0]
    j = np.random.randint(1,w-1,1)[0]
    c = count_nbrs(im, i, j, th)
    im1[i,j] = 255*(prob[c] > 0.5) 
plt.imshow(im1, 'gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

The next animation shows how the binary image is generated using the above code.

[image]

Comment: What's `nbd` please?

Comment: Neighborhood, generally 4 & 8 neighbor pixels around one are considered

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code. You have 4 lines `count += np.mean() > th`. Is this to average the RGB values of each of the 4 neighbours? If so, it is rather wasteful since you make 2 passes over the image and average most pixels as a neighbour above, neighbour below, neighbour left and neighbour on right side. Surely you could calculate the average just once and save it, instead of 8 times?

Comment: You are right. This could be done more efficiently by creating an intermediate grayscale image. However, for a small image it would not matter that much (since it will provide a linear speedup w.r.t. time complexity) it would increase space complexity and i did not want to create an intermediate image. The goal of the implementation was to demonstrate how Markov chain can be used to convert a color image directly to a binary image. If time complexity is a concern, we should create an intermediate image to remove redundant `np.mean()`s. Finally, train / test images can be different (here same).